# How do I push key/value to array

Tags: php

I have some data that I am trying to push to an array (key/value)

My code is below but when i try and print the array, its empty.

What am I missing?

```
$dataArray = array();
foreach($dataTypes as $data) 
{
    $dataArray[$data->dataID] .= $data->type;
}
print_r($dataArray);
```

Edit

This is what $dataTypes looks like.

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [dataID] => 1
    [type] => Account Number
    [description] => User Account Number
    [whoAdded] => carl
    [whenAdded] => 2014-05-14T00:00:00
)
```

**Solution**
Due to it being XML, I had to cast the vars to int and string

`$dataArray[(int)$data->dataID] = (string)$data->type;`

Comment: why `.=` and have tried to print the values in loop

Comment: I removed it and still the same outcome with the empty array. Yes, the results print fine within that loop

Comment: Have you tried printing/echoing $data->dataID and $data->type in the foreach loop?

Comment: Fixed it, needed to change the string types `$dataArray[(int)$data->dataID] = (string)$data->type;` thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$dataArray = array();
foreach($dataTypes as $data) 
{
$dataArray[$data->dataID] = $data->type;
}
print_r($dataArray);
```

Comment: You're using `.=`, is it what you want?

Comment: The .= won't make a difference... He is getting an empty array after the loop, even with .= he should be getting something inserted.

Comment: I thought you just can use `.=` to add something to variable but the variable should exist. But thanks.